# Running the Django REST framework example with Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to adapt the example shown on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ to Django 2.0, but I'm running into an error.

Firstly, I created a project using `django-admin startproject rest_example`. I've added `'rest_framework'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py` and added the `REST_FRAMEWORK` variable:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Here is my adapted `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

The problem is that when I `python manage.py runserver` and navigate to `localhost:8000`, I get a 404:

[image]

Similarly, if I navigate to `localhost:8000/api-auth/`, I get

[image]

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by changing the definition of `urlpatterns` to

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

and also running `python manage.py migrate` before running the server. Now if I go to `localhost:8000/users/` I get a user list view:

[image]

where I've run `python manage.py createsuperuser` once to create a (dummy) user.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add the urls to their own sub-path by:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

But otherwise having a database setup and a user record in it will definitely be needed for your example to function as expected ;-)